# Different db connections string for different environments in Play

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

In Rails it's possible to specify different connections string for different environments:

```
#database.yml

development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000


production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: 
  username: 
  password:
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Is there any way to do the same in Play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our project we keep two configuration files - `dev_application.conf` and `prod_application.conf` and run the application like this:

```
play -Dconfig.file=/conf/dev_application.conf run
```

or

```
play -Dconfig.file=/conf/prod_application.conf start
```

Comment: and what are you doing in case there are some common (not depending on the environment) settings? copy-paste is not DRY.

Comment: There are not so many settings that are common for dev and prod environment, and they don't change very often (I'd even say they almost never change) so we just keep them duplicated.

Comment: I found out you could do "include" to keep it DRY.

Comment: Yes, I already saw this question\answer, just too lazy to rewrite it now :) Thanks for info